# Remove \n newline if string contains keyword

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk, newline

I'd like to know if I can remove a `\n` (newline) only if the current line has one ore more keywords from a list; for instance, I want to remove the `\n` if it contains the words *hello* or *world*.

**Example:**

```
this is an original
file with lines
containing words like hello
and world
this is the end of the file
```

**And the result would be:**

```
this is an original
file with lines
containing words like hello and world this is the end of the file
```

I'd like to use sed, or awk and, if needed, grep, wc or whatever commands work for this purpose. I want to be able to do this on a lot of files.

Comment: Do you want the desired output to *replace* the contents of the file?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have all changes so that only those lines containing keywords have their \n removed and have the file saved

Comment: Should the last line contain a newline if it contains  the keyword?

Comment: Should only whole words match? E.g., should `worlds` be considered a match of keyword `word`, or not?

Comment: @potong in my case it doesn't matter, whatever is easier, if adding a newline is too much trouble then it doesn't matter

Comment: @mklement0 yes, worlds would be considered as a match for world

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy: Thanks; do the keywords then have to match at the *beginning* of words? `worlds` matches keyword `world`, as you say, but does `aworlds` match, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is simple one using sed

```
sed -r ':a;$!{N;ba};s/((hello|world)[^\n]*)\n/\1 /g' file
```

#### Explanation

- `:a;$!{N;ba}` read whole file into pattern, like this: `this is an original\nfile with lines\ncontaining words like hell\
  o\nand world\nthis is the end of the file$`
- `s/((hello|world)[^\n]*)\n/\1 /g` search the key words `hello` or `world` and remove the next `\n`,
- `g` command in sed substitute stands to apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the first.

Comment: +1 for the logic. Though you are missing a space, `...\n/\1 /g'`

Comment: +1, very clever (though reading the entire file at once may not always be an option).

Answer (score 4):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '/hello|world/{printf "%s ", $0; next} 1' file
this is an original
file with lines
containing words like hello and world this is the end of the file
```

Comment: +1; it's not clear whether this is a requirement, but it may make sense to only match on word boundaries; Linux: `/\<(hello|world)\>/`; OSX (incredibly, `awk` doesn't support word-boundary matching there): `/(^|[[:punct:][:space:]])(hello|world)($|[[:punct:][:space:]])/`

Comment: Thanks but since OP is matching `words` and `words` both by `word` I guess word boundaries aren't needed.

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex approach:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        # define the word list
        w["hello"]
        w["world"]
    }
    {
        printf "%s", $0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
            if ($i in w) {
                printf " "
                next
            }
        print ""
    }
'
```

or a perl one-liner

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN {@w = qw(hello world)} s/\n/ / if grep {$_ ~~ @w} split'
```

---

To edit the file in-place, do:

```
awk '...' filename > tmpfile && mv tmpfile filename
perl -i -pe '...' filename
```

Comment: How do I add the name of the file I want to do this in?

Comment: Just put it at the end of the command: `perl -pe '...' filename`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;/^.*(hello|world).*\'\''/M{$bb;N;ba};:b;s/\n/ /g' file
```

This checks if the last line, of a possible multi-line, contains the required string(s) and if so reads another line until end-of-file or such that the last line does not contain the/those string(s). Newlines are removed and the line printed.

Comment: +1, though not exactly easy to understand; explanation of the `M` (multi-line) modifier and the `\'` (end of buffer) assertion (inadvertently obfuscated by the shell's quoting requirements) here: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{ORS=(/hello|world/?FS:RS)}1' file
this is an original
file with lines
containing words like hello and world this is the end of the file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '
:beg
/hello/ b keep
/world/ b keep
H;s/.*//;x;s/\n/ /g;p;b
: keep
H;s/.*//
$ b beg
' YourFile
```

a bit harder due to check on current line that may include a previous *hello* or *world* already

principle:

on every pattern match, keep the string in hold buffer
other wise, load hold buffer and remove \n (use of swap and empty the current line due to limited buffer operation available) and print the content
Add a special case of pattern in last line (normaly hold so not printed otherwise)